# Sqlalchemy: insert a collection of values into a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a Posts table and a collection of Post instances, I want to insert all the instances into the Posts table.

I use:

```
    def add_posts(self,posts):
        for post in posts:
            self.session.merge(post)
        self.session.commit()
```

Is there an option for not doing it iteratively? i.e. something like:

```
    def add_posts(self,posts):
        self.session.**merge_all**(posts)
        self.session.commit()
```

Comment: Does [`merge_result()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.merge_result) help?

Comment: Are those `Post` instances from another session, or freshly created instances? If latter, use [`Session.add_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all).